# Multiple keyboards for different purposes

Tags: keyboard

This feels like a very odd request but feel like it should be possible within Linux.

I'm running the latest version of Raspbian with kernel version 4.1

What I'm trying to achieve is to have two keyboards (one is actually a Logitech Harmony Remote) connected to a single Raspberry Pi but only have one control the OS.

I have `/dev/input/event2` which appears to be my wired keyboard and `/dev/input/event6` which is my remote.

I'd like the wired keyboard to work as normal, but the remote to do absolutely nothing so I can capture the events using NodeJS (already tested and works fine, but the remote controls the OS which causes issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python evdev can do exactly what you are asking.

https://python-evdev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apidoc.html#evdev.device.InputDevice.grab

Comment: Thanks, looks spot on! Just got to work out how to do this in NodeJS now :)